# JDA - how to use getUsersByName()

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am currently working on a discord bot and want it to tag other users on the server, whose name(s) the bot gets through a text channel like this:
!harass RoverKnight
! is the bot's prefix, harass the method in which I want to tag the name given, in this case RoverKnight.
However, to tag someone I need their id, which I want the bot to retrieve itself by using the `JDA.getUsersByName(String name, boolean ignoreCase)` method.
The problem I'm running into is that this is a non-static method, so I can't call it in my Main class or Harass class (Harass extends Thread btw), and I can't instantiate a JDA object because JDA is abstract, so I'm kinda stuck (also I'm pretty new to programming, so that's probably contributing). Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [JDA README](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA), you can instantiate a `JDA` object from a bot token using:

```java
JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("your_bot_token").build();
```

This README contains more code examples which will likely be of use to you, so I recommend giving it at least a brief look.

Comment: Good to hear. If this answer was the solution to your question, then you should mark it as the accepted answer.